# PHP print 0 for months not returned by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using google charts API to plot some data. I am grabbing the data from a MySQL database and printing it using MySQL.

```
<?php

$income_from_clients = $mysql_obj->select ( "
    SELECT
    sum(invoice.invoice_amount_payable) AS invoice_totals, 
    company.company_label AS company_label,
    MONTHNAME(invoice.invoice_date_paid) AS month,
    YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid) AS year
    FROM invoice INNER JOIN company ON invoice.company_id = company.company_id
    WHERE 
    invoice.invoice_active=1
    AND invoice.invoice_status_id=7
    AND invoice.invoice_date_deleted=0
    AND invoice.invoice_date_paid>='" . $_POST ["start_date_"] . "-" . $_POST ["start_date_month"] . "-" . $_POST ["start_date_date"] . "'
    AND invoice.invoice_date_paid<='" . $_POST ["end_date_"] . "-" . $_POST ["end_date_month"] . "-" . $_POST ["end_date_date"] . "'
    AND company.company_id=" . $_POST ["company_id"] . "
    GROUP BY company.company_id, MONTH(invoice.invoice_date_paid), YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid)
    ORDER BY  YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid), MONTH(invoice.invoice_date_paid)" );

echo "data.addRows($mysql_obj->mysql_num_rows);";

$i = 0;
foreach ( $income_from_clients as $ifc ) {
    echo "data.setValue($i, 0, '" . $ifc ["month"] . " " . $ifc ["year"] . "');\n";
    echo "data.setValue($i, 1, " . $ifc ["invoice_totals"] . ");\n";
    $i ++;
}

?>
```

This is working fine however any months where there has not been an invoice is simply skipped on the chart as it isn't returned returned from the MySQL. How would I get it to plot a 0 for these months?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill holes in the data in MySQL, you need to join it with a reference table (calender in your case).

See - [Using a Join to Fill in Holes in a List](http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-chp-12-sect-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're iterating over the results from the database and outputting values based on the rows it returns. Since it doesn't return the rows with a value of 0, you won't see those in your output.

Two viable solutions include:

- Modify your SQL so that it returns the rows with a value of 0 (see Sukumar's answer)
- Change your PHP so that it iterates over the year/month combinations you are interested in and outputs the value from the database or 0 if there isn't one. I'm not sure which ones you are "interested in", but you might be able to iterate FROM "smallest year/monthcombination returned from the db" TO "largest year/monthcombination returned from the db" (or current year/month). If you do this, you'll likely want to iterate through the results in the database and put them in a (year/month -> value) map... then iterate over the dateranges and pull values from the map.